# lapply on a model output and summarize the results

Tags: r, lapply

I run a model on several variables using lapply, now I have to extract a specific part of the output. here is an example:

```
require(emmeans)
require(lmerTest)


mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl,levels=c(4,6,8),
   labels=c("4cyl","6cyl","8cyl"))

dvList <- names(mtcars)[3:10]

model <- lapply(dvList, function(x) {
    lm(substitute(i~cyl, list(i = as.name(x))), data = mtcars)})

all<-lapply(model,emmeans,"cyl")
```

What I need to do is combine all the columns named "emmean" in each model, after renaming it using the corresponding variable name, in a single dataset.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to know is that `emmeans()` produces an object of class `"emmGrid"` (not a data frame). So you need to use `as.data.frame()` to convert it to a form where you can extract a column of values. Thus, do something like this:

```
names(all) <- dvList
tbl <- sapply(all, function(emm) as.data.frame(emm)$emmean)
tbl
```

The results are

```
        disp        hp     drat       wt     qsec           vs        am     gear
[1,] 105.1364  82.63636 4.070909 2.285727 19.13727 9.090909e-01 0.7272727 4.090909
[2,] 183.3143 122.28571 3.585714 3.117143 17.97714 5.714286e-01 0.4285714 3.857143
[3,] 353.1000 209.21429 3.229286 3.999214 16.77214 2.220446e-16 0.1428571 3.285714
```

Comment: rvl, thank you so much ...  One more thing what if the emman variables are not equal, which is the case since I have missing values in the original  variables. Again thank you

Comment: Well hen it will return a list rather than a matrix, unless you change the function somehow so it always returns a vector of the same length

Comment: rvl,  can we use merge function within sapply?